# Replacing text in a range and keeping the formatting in Word VSTO

Tags: c#, ms-word, ms-office, vsto

There is a similar question similar to this one but it's about retaining paragraph formatting. That person doesn't just plainly set the text, he is copying and pasting it.

---

Hello. I am trying to replace some text in my word document via a Word VSTO Add-in. The problem is that whenever I do that, the first found formatting is taken and replaced all over the document. So for example if the first line looks like this :

**a**, *b*, ***c***

the entire document would be just in bold. This is how I am replacing the text :

```
object start = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveDocument.Content.Start;
object end = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveDocument.Content.End;

Word.Range range = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveDocument.Range(start, end);

string pattern = "textToReplace";
Regex regex = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
range.FormattedText = regex.Replace(range.Text, "textToReplaceWith", 1);
```

Comment: What do you hope to gain by using `FormattedText` in this context? It usually only makes sense if you're picking up formatted text from another place in Word. Do you get a better result if you use `Range.Text` instead?

Comment: I did use Range.Text before even creating this topic which I should've mentioned. But sadly no, the results are the same.

Comment: Ah, OK, now I see what you're doing. You're replacing Word's entire content in that the last line of code. (BTW, your edit has made the code incorrect - remove either Text or FormattedText) The result of regex is a string. This is the same as if you were to do: range.Text = "My string". And then it will all be formatted the same. If you want to replace throughout the document and respect the formatting you must use Word's `Range.Find` object. You can use regex.Replace to get the string value for Replacement.Text, but you can't use regex.replace.